# statsmodels mosaic plot - how to order categories

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, mosaic

Here is dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic

df = pd.DataFrame({'size' : ['small', 'large', 'large', 'small', 'large', 'small'],
'length' : ['long', 'short', 'short', 'long', 'long', 'short']})
```

if I plot it `mosaic(df, ['size', 'length'])` it will display `size` in this order `small` then `large`, while I would like to have `large` and then `small`. Is there way to achieve it?

Comment: Just sort the `size` column: `mosaic(df.sort_values('size'), ['size', 'length'])`

Comment: @NickilMaveli very smart approach! You can post it as an official answer, if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort values present in the size column to alter the order.

```
mosaic(df.sort_values('size'), ['size', 'length'])
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But now what about the `length` order...? :-(